# Query for Opportunities

Tags: soql, opportunity

Can you guyz help me to query for all the opportunities that are in between stages 0-5 and has closed date Greater than today.

Thanks

Comment: Ravi -- as a matter of etiquette on this community; showing effort on your part is appreciated rather than just asking folks to 'do the work for you'

Answer (score 3):

What did you mean by between stages 0-5? The following just uses the standard first 5 stages, if you meant other values just edit the conditions:

```
[SELECT StageName, CloseDate FROM Opportunity WHERE (StageName = 'Prospecting' OR StageName = 'Qualification' OR StageName = 'Needs Analysis' OR StageName = 'Value Proposition' OR StageName = 'Id. Decision Makers') AND CloseDate > TODAY];
```

Comment: I meant stages of an oppurtunity like prospect, and so on

Comment: Then you should be fine, like I said I just used the standard first 5 stages